# How do I put a container next to another container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put my container (box) next to my other container (box). Instead of them being next to each other, they end up being above/below each other. I'd prefer them to be next to each other instead of this.

This is my code;

```
<div id="blog">
<img src="images/mlblog.png">
  <img src="images/mltownareaconcept.png" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
    <p>Check out the town area concept!</p>
    <p><a href="http://community.mooselounge.me/blog/">Click here to read the blog!</a></p>
```

```
#blog {
  background: url(-) repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #855E42;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#forums {
  background: url(-) repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #855E42;
  margin-left: 900px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to "float" one of your containers and remove your "margin-left".

```
#blog {
  background: url(-) repeat;
  border: 2px solid #855E42;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

#forums {
  background: url(-) repeat;
  border: 2px solid #855E42;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but it wasn't working. However, it seems I did a mistake with the syntax. Hahah, classical. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML I don't see a Div for forums...You need to add a a float:left to #blog and #forums if you want them to sit next to each other

```
#blog {
background: url(-) repeat;
border: 2px solid #855E42;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
}

#forums {
background: url(-) repeat;
border: 2px solid #855E42;
float:left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
}

<div id="blog">Your code...</div>
<div id="forums">Your code...</div>
```

Comment: The forums have float: right, since they are next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

if case of both containers having same height, you can use this style:

```
#blog, #forums { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a clearing div below blog and forum.

```
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Also Thomas suggested float the forum div to right.

Good luck with that.